# Twig adding "%0A" to imagepath (Email-Template)

Tags: html, templates, twig

i am havin problems with some image urls generated partly through twig.
Here is how i am currently doing it:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{% set imageurl %}
http://www.someurl.com/mails/images/emails
{% endset %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

And this is how i am using it in the template itself:

```
{{imageurl}}/spacer.gif
```

The problem now is, that these images are not getting displayed properly in the final email because of a "%0A" inside the url. It looks like this:

```
/emails%0A/spacer.gif
```

I have no idea what is causing this problem, maybe you guys can help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%0A` is the [Line Feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Feed) character. It is appended because of the newline after `.../emails`.

Either set the variable in one line:

```
{% set imageurl %}http://www.someurl.com/mails/images/emails{% endset %}
```

Or use Twig's [tag level whitespace control](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control):

```
{%- set imageurl -%}
http://www.someurl.com/mails/images/emails
{%- endset -%}
```

Comment: I have already used the first solution. I didn't know about the second one. Thanks a lot! Will mark your answer as correct as soon as i can